# TSQL Join to replace a union

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, union, union-all

I have two tables similar to the following:

**Profile table**

```
Id | ServiceId | AccessLevel
----------------------------
1  | 123       | 1
2  | 123       | 1
3  | 123       | 2
```

**Additional Profile table** (ProfileId is a foreign key to Profile.Id)

```
Id | ProfileId | AccessLevel
----------------------------
1  | 1         | 2
2  | 1         | 3
3  | 2         | 2
4  | 3         | 3
```

I current have a view which does a UNION ALL on these two tables so that I can query for it "ProfileId = 1" and get the following resultset:

```
ProfileId | ServiceId | AccessLevel
-----------------------------------
1         | 123       | 1
1         | 123       | 2
1         | 123       | 3
```

**This seems to be very slow.**

So, I am wondering if/how I can get this same resultset using a single query but am struggling to work out a way to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Query behind the view:

```
SELECT Id, ServiceId, AccessLevel FROM Profile
UNION ALL
SELECT P.Id, P.ServiceId, A.AccessLevel
FROM Profile P
INNER JOIN AdditionalProfile A ON A.ProfileId = P.Id
```

Each table contains approx. 160,000 records.

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN required (if any table is empty.) I'd guess UNION ALL is better... Are you sure it's slow?!?

Comment: If you have a slow query post the QUERY and the QUERY PLAN, number of records etc. No one can help you optimise it based on the info provided.

Comment: I have added the query from the view.

Comment: What sort of performance would you expect (in terms of time elapsed), and what are you getting? Also, would you rather see optimum performance when querying for a single ID, or for all IDs?

Comment: Just looking at your query, I don't understand what you're trying to do.  So, you want to select all rows from the `Profile` table and then select from the same `Profile` table the records which are also in `AdditionalProfile`, leaving you with duplicates?  One way to speed this up would be to make your query simply `SELECT p.Id, p.ServiceId, p.AccessLevel, a.Id FROM Profile P LEFT JOIN AdditionalProfile A on P.Id = A.ProfileId` -- this will give you the same *data* you're looking for but a different resultset.  Instead of duplicates, you'd have a third column that is either `null` or not.

Comment: The Profile table has one record for each person, the AdditionalProfile table has multiple records for "additional profiles". I want the record from Profile PLUS the record(s) from AdditionalProfile in one resultset.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p1.Id, p1.ServiceId, COALESCE(p2.AccessLevel, p1.AccessLevel)
  FROM Profile p1
  left join AdditionalProfile p2
    on p2.ProfileId = p1.Id
   and p2.AccessLevel <> p1.AccessLevel
```

Could use ISNULL rather than COALESCE

The problem with a (normal) view is then no indexes

Better yet make it into a stored procedure
If Id and ProfileId are indexed this will be smoking fast

```
SELECT p1.Id, p1.ServiceId, ISNULL(p2.AccessLevel, p1.AccessLevel)
  FROM Profile p1
  left join AdditionalProfile p2
    on p2.ProfileId = p1.Id
   and p2.AccessLevel <> p1.AccessLevel 
 where p1.ID = @ID
```

ok try

```
SELECT p1.Id, p1.ServiceId, COALESCE(p2.AccessLevel, p1.AccessLevel)
  FROM Profile p1
 outer join AdditionalProfile p2
    on p2.ProfileId = p1.Id
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but this doesn't work. It will only return the record from the AdditionalProfile table.

Comment: @kmcoulson No it does not only return only the AdditionalProfile records.  A left join returns all rows on the left - that is what a left join does.

Comment: Sorry, to explain a bit further. I need the record from Profile AND the record(s) from AdditionalProfile (I.e. 1 row from Profile, 2 rows from AdditionalProfile, 3 rows altogether). Your suggestion will only return "AccessLevel" values from the AdditionalProfile table unless no records exist in that table then it will return the "AccessLevel" value from Profile.

Comment: 1) The bad performance can be due lack of indexes between that tables. 2) I guess the best way is to use union but on selects filtering the Id and without any join. Just select from [Profile] where {filter} union select from [AdditionalProfile] where {filter}